# Convert character set from none-standard one to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, php, express, encoding, iconv

There is a page with `<meta charset="EUC-KR">`, say address-search.foo.com that searches an address and sends it to a specified url by submitting html form of method POST like below.

```
let form = <form element>;
form.zipCode.value = "63563";
form.address.value = "제주특별자치도 서귀포시 이어도로 579 (강정동)";
form.action = "https://my-service.foo.com";
form.method = "post";
form.submit();
```

And there is a POST handler in my-service.foo.com run by ExpressJs to take the above request like below.

```
const next = require("next");
const app = next(nextConfig);

const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  app.render(req, res, "/");
});
```

And the console.log(req.body); above prints below.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  zipCode: '63563'
  address: '����Ư����ġ�� �������� �̾�� 579 (������)'
}
```

I tried to convert the encoding of `req.body.address` using `iconv-lite` module, but it doesn't work as it does on PHP like below.

```
iconv("CP949", "UTF-8", $_POST['address']); // working very happily
```

How to properly use `iconv-lite` or is there anyway to get around this on ExpressJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [urlencode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlencode) module.

I solved it by using `bodyParser.raw()` instead of `bodyParser.urlencoded()`.

```
const urlencode = require("urlencode");
const iconv = require("iconv-lite");
const qs = require("querystring");

server.use(
  bodyParser.raw({ type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      const decoded = iconv.decode(req.body, "utf8");
      /**
       * Define another conditional statement that filters an encoding specific case.
       * Below if statement is just for my case.
       */
      if (req.path === "/some/path/to/treat/differently") {
        req.body = urlencode.parse(decoded, { charset: "euc-kr" })
      }
      else {
        req.body = qs.parse(decoded);
      }
    }
    next();
  }
);
```